# How to display .svn dirs in package explorer / navigator / project explorer, in Eclipse subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I want to be able to see the .svn directories when I look at a files and directory view in eclipse. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Project Explorer view locate a down facing triangle in the upper right corner. That will activate a pull down menu. Select Customize View and then turn off ".* resources" filter. This filter removes files and directories with names that start with ".".

Comment: @ohadshai: did you try to close/reopen your project after modifying the filter selection?

Comment: +1. That normally works for me. In Eclipse Helios the selection in the dropdown is called "Filters.." instead of "Customize View"

Comment: @vonC: tried close the project and restart eclipse - didn't help. It's seems that it is something that is related to subclipse, because other dot-something files are displayed (for example ".project").

Comment: @ohadshai: interesting. That would mean that if you uninstall that subclipse plugin, all the `.svn` directories would then appear? (after restarting Eclipse)

Comment: Subclipse could be adding its own filter on top of the standard ".* resources" filter. If it is, there should be an entry for that in the filters dialog. Should not need to uninstall the plugin to get the folders to show up.

Comment: @ohadshai: good point by @Konstantin: does subclipse add its own `*.svn` filter entry?

Comment: @K from what I remember without subclipse Eclipse shows the .svn dirs . it is easy to test it, just create a .svn dir and see if it is visible.